# ng-style showing console error for background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image

I have the following `ng-style` in my HTML:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + image + ')'}"></div>
```

Then my Angular code sets the image variable by bringing in a URL from an API call like so:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){

  $http.get("/api/image").success(function(data){
    $scope.image = data.image;
  });

});
```

The image variable ends up looking like this: 
`//images.contentful.com/xxxxxxx/my-image.jpg`

The image displays fine, except Chrome throws the following issue in console:
`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

I can get rid of this error by adding `http://` like so:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(http://' + image + ')'}"></div>
```

Chrome understands to render this as `http://images.contentful.com/xxxxxxx/my-image.jpg` but IE renders it as `http:////images.contentful.com/xxxxxxx/my-image.jpg` and doesn't work.

If I just have `http:` the error comes back in console but the images work in IE.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you make sure your webserver is configured correctly? So, are all the mime-types set?
You say your variable looks like `//images.contentful.com/xxxxxxx/my-image.jpg`. Doesn't that mean you to prepend it with just `http:`

Comment: I'm using a MEAN stack. I think Node and Express configure mime-types automatically, not sure though.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese prepending `http:` does work in all browsers but still shows the console error in Chrome.

Comment: try relative path `<div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(//' + image + ')'}"></div>`

Comment: @pankajparkar the variable it brings in already has the "//" so adding another 2 would render "////" on IE

Comment: @Coop version of IE please..

Comment: It makes sense. If image = `//images.contentful.com/xxxxx/my-image.jpg` and I add '//' to the beginning of that, obviously it will try to render `////images.contentful.com/xxxxx/my-image.jpg`

Comment: @Coop did you tried that..or just you are saying..could you create a problem with plunkr

Comment: @pankajparkar yes of course. My question explains how the various scenarios render in both Chrome and IE. I could only know that if I had tried it in both.

Comment: could you mind to create a fiddle or plunkr??